# How Can i pass the Basic Credentials while using REST API client Program

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0

Client client = Client.create();

```
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("username", "password"));
        WebResource resource = client.resource("https://server.location.path");
        //WebResource.Builder builder=resource.getRequestBuilder().header("Authorization", "Basic Base64value");
        ClientResponse response = resource.accept("application/json")
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
        System.out.println(response);
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        System.out.println(output);
```

Here i have been placed the code and please let me know is you have any suggestion please

Comment: Is there a question/problem? The _"How"_ is answered in your code. And the code above is Jersey 1.x, not 2.x, like you have tagged.

Comment: caution, if your're using a jersey1 client with jersey2 server you will enconter some incompatibilities, and mybe that this issue is related to that.

Comment: Basically this is the question but  i have pasted snippiest code to understand better my problem, My Concerns is, How can we  Pass Basic Base64 credentials with the REst client using Jersey Api.